# Why I can not find reference to iText document?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I added the **itextpdf-5.5.4** jar file in my project but still I cant not find reference to the methods of the library.

```
getContentPane().add(tPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
Document d = new Document();
```

I can only find reference to the Document class of **javax.swing.text**.

[image: Added itext jar file]

Comment: Not enough information to help you. Where is the file located? How are you adding it to the classpath? It seems your problem is the file was not added to the classpath. Are you using eclipse, netbeans.. ?

Comment: No way to tell as asked--maybe you did it wrong.

Comment: You have to add the library to the app's classpath by right clicking on it -> add to classpath

Comment: In your question you say version 5.5.4, but your screenshot says 5.5.13.

Comment: I updated and thought if it would work with some latest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue. I had **javax.swing.text.** imported. After I cleaned unused imports and the try to import **itext** it worked.

I think the reason is javax.swing.text has document class implemented that's why it was showing that class and preventing me form importing anything for the same class.